# The column name id was not found in this ResultSet. i just want sum fee, sum amount and get column merchant_id

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

my repository:

```
 @Query(value = "Select SUM(th.FEE_AMOUNT) as fee, SUM(th.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) as amount,th.MERCHANT_ID " +
        "from TRANSACTION_HISTORY th where th.TRANSACTION_GROUP=:transGroup " +
        "and (th.TRANSACTION_STATUS not in(1,2)) and th.SRC_SYSTEM_ERROR_CODE = '00' " +
        "and th.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN :startDate And :endDate group by th.MERCHANT_ID " +
        "order by th.MERCHANT_ID asc", nativeQuery = true)
List<TransactionHistory> selectTrxWd(@Param("transGroup") String transGroup, @Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

my controller :

```
List<TransactionHistory> transhisList = transactionHistoryRepository.selectTrxWd("PAYMENT", startDate, date2);
```

Comment: Let me guess `TransactionHistory` is an entity. You should map your result to a dto not an entity.

Comment: like this?

'import id.co.istdigitalplatform.domain.entity.Merchant;
import lombok.Data;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
public class TrxDto {
    private BigDecimal fee;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private Merchant merchant_id;
}
'

Comment: Please don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable.

Comment: like this? 
List<TrxDto> selectTrxNow(@Param("transGroup") String transGroup, @Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);